# Can I use the USB port of the raspberry pi (model B+) for serial communication (RS232)

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi

I need to interface an old machine (thermostream) to interface with the raspberry pi (model B+)

The thermostream device has a RS232 serial port and I want to connect it to the USB port of the raspberry pi using the RS232 serial to usb cable (where the usb end of the cable is inserted in the pi and the serial end is connected to the device). And I need to write the code in python.

IS this possible? If yes, how should I proceed? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. First you need to install [pyserial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/)

Then, in Python, you can use the following function to create a serial object that connects to a port. The usb ports on the pi are dynamically assigned a name and those names can change. This function will enable you to loop through each port for the name. (might not work well with multiple devices attached). Check your connection settings on the device you wish to communicate with (baudrate, parity, stopbits etc) and modify the code to use those settings.

```
import serial

def serialConnect(): 
    serlocations=['/dev/ttyACM', '/dev/ttyACM0', '/dev/ttyACM1','/dev/ttyACM2', '/dev/ttyACM3','/dev/ttyACM4', '/dev/ttyACM5','/dev/ttyUSB0','/dev/ttyUSB1','/dev/ttyUSB2','/dev/ttyUSB3', '/dev/ttyUSB4', '/dev/ttyUSB5', '/dev/ttyUSB6', '/dev/ttyUSB7', '/dev/ttyUSB8', '/dev/ttyUSB9', '/dev/ttyUSB10','/dev/ttyS0', '/dev/ttyS1', '/dev/ttyS2', 'com2', 'com3', 'com4', 'com5', 'com6', 'com7', 'com8', 'com9', 'com10', 'com11', 'com12', 'com13', 'com14', 'com15', 'com16', 'com17', 'com18', 'com19', 'com20', 'com21', 'com1', 'end']
    for device in serlocations:
        try:
            ser = serial.Serial(
                port=device,
                baudrate=9600,
                parity=serial.PARITY_ODD,
                stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_TWO,
                bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS
            )
            print device
            return ser  
        except:
            x=0 
    if device == 'end':
        print "No Device Found"     

ser = serialConnect()
if ser:
    ser.write("TEST")
    ser.timeout=5
    for i in ser.readlines():
        print i
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have already tried it but it seems to not work. anything else that i can try

Comment: For serial interface, pyserial is the best option (It's actually the only option I am aware of).  If it isn't working, check that there is something to read coming in for ser.readlines(), or that your device is listening for something that you are sending with ser.write(). I am not familiar with your specific device but you may consider using an Arduino to Serial.print() to the pi to ensure that the receive channel is working.

Comment: it just sits and wait for the message, what i am trying is to try and receive what I am sending from the pi. For this I have connected the RX and TX pins of RS232 and made ground common.

Comment: Just added a writing procedure to the answer. Are you using USB or the direct RX-TX pins from the pi?

Comment: USB is connected to the pi and the RX and TX of the RS232 Serial end is connected to each other (this is done so that I can read what I am writing i.e. to read what I am sending from the pi)

Comment: I have tried the above code as well as I have tried a small code as follows:
import serial
port = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', baudrate = 9600, timeout = 3)
port.write('Test')
a = port.readlines()
print a

But I am not getting anything

Comment: it started working now, one the things I changed was the USB cable and also reverted some of the changes in the raspberry pi  and rebooted the pi, thanks for all your help :)

Comment: I modified the code I posted to fix a few bugs and I verified that it works with an Arduino UNO. If this has helped you, mark this as the answer.